# How to compare dates in Wollok?

Tags: wollok

I have an event and I need to know if it happened after some date. How can I compare two dates in Wollok?

```
object event {
    var date
    method hasAlreadyHappened() {
        // how can I compare the event date with today?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use comparison operators such as >, <, >=, <=

```
>>> new Date(12,9,2017) > new Date(10, 9, 2017)
true
>>> new Date(12,9,2017) >= new Date(12, 9, 2017)
true
```